# hibernate not locating junction table in query of many to many relationship

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

In a spring mvc application using hibernate and jpa, I have a many to many relationship between a `WordKey` entity and a `Concept` entity.  `WordKey` has a `concepts` collection, and `Concept` has a `wordkeys` collection.  I DO NOT want to use `fetchType=EAGER` because performance is an issue.  Instead, once a `WordKey` has been selected by a user, I want to populate a `Collection<Concept>` with the results of a query that takes `selectedKeyWord` `wk` as a parameter and returns the collection of `concepts` that is associated with that `WordKey` in the underlying database.  How do I write this query in JPQL?

Here is the query that I have so far.  It is not working (see error further below):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Collection<Concept> findConceptsForKeyWord(ConcWordKey wk) {
    Query query = this.em.createQuery(
        "SELECT DISTINCT concept FROM Concept concept join concept.wordkeys k WHERE k.name =:wk"
    );
    query.setParameter("wk", wk.getName());
    Collection<Concept> result = (Collection<Concept>) query.getResultList();
    return result;
}
```

Here is the hibernate query that is being generated by the above code.  Note that it is looking for an imaginary `concept_wordkey` table instead of using the `wordkey_junction` join table that is specified in the `WordKey` entity code further below:

```
select distinct conc0_.effectiveTime as effectiv1_52_,
 conc0_.id as id2_52_,
 from concept conc0_
 inner join concept_wordkey wordkeys1_
 on conc0_.effectiveTime=wordkeys1_.concept_effectiveTime
 and conc0_.id=wordkeys1_.concept_id
 inner join wordkey conc2_
 on wordkeys1_.wordkeys_keyword=conc2_.keyword
 where conc2_.keyword=?
```

The specific error being generated in the stack trace is:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:  
Table 'mydb.concept_wordkey' doesn't exist
```

Here is the `Concept` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "concept")
public class Concept implements Serializable{

    @EmbeddedId
    public EmbedPK conceptPk;

    @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<WordKey> wordkeys;

    public EmbedPK getConceptPk(){return conceptPk;}

    protected Set<WordKey> getWordkeysInternal() {
        if (this.wordkeys == null) {this.wordkeys = new HashSet<WordKey>();}
        return this.wordkeys;
    }

    public List<WordKey> getWordkeys() {
        List<WordKey> sortedWordkeys = new ArrayList<WordKey>(getWordkeysInternal());
        PropertyComparator.sort(sortedWordkeys, new MutableSortDefinition("wordkey", true, true));
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(sortedWordkeys);
    }

    public WordKey getWordkey(String s) {return getWordkey(s, false);}

    public WordKey getWordkey(String ps, boolean ignoreNew) {
        ps = ps.toLowerCase();
        for (WordKey s1 : getWordkeysInternal()) {
            if (!ignoreNew || !s1.isNew()) {
                String keyword = s1.getName();
                keyword = keyword.toLowerCase();
                if (keyword.equals(ps)) {return s1;}
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the `WordKey` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "wordkey")
public class WordKey {

    @Id
    @Column(name="keyword")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="wordkey_junction",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="keyword")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="conceptid"),@JoinColumn(name="effectiveTime")})
    private Set<Concept> concepts = new HashSet<Concept>();

    public String getName(){return name;}
    public void setName(String nm){name=nm;}

    protected Set<Concept> getConceptsInternal() {
        if (this.concepts == null) {this.concepts = new HashSet<Concept>();}
        return this.concepts;
    }

    public List<Concept> getConcepts() {
        List<Concept> sortedConcepts = new ArrayList<Concept>(getConceptsInternal());
        PropertyComparator.sort(sortedConcepts, new MutableSortDefinition("conceptid", true, true));
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(sortedConcepts);
    }

    public Concept getConcept(BigInteger s) {return getConcept(s, false);}

    public Concept getConcept(BigInteger ps, boolean ignoreNew) {
        for (Concept s1 : getConceptsInternal()) {
            if (!ignoreNew || !s1.isNew()) {
                BigInteger compName = s1.getConceptPk().getId();
                if (compName == ps) {return s1;}
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a mappedBy in your `@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})` in your `Concept` class. Add change your annotation to `@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="concepts")` and try it again.

You need this to tell Hibernate to map your many-to-many collection of `wordKey`'s to the collection of `Concept`'s on the `WordKey` class, which will in turn expose your `wordkey_junction` table to the collection.

If that doesn't work or you don't want a bidirectional relationship, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You need to Specify mid (xref) Table.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name = "midTableName",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "foreignKey")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "OtherEntityForeignKey")})
```

**Note** -This is the General way of ManyToMany Mapping with normalization. you can get a Good answer if you can update the question with table structure..